# How to remove permission of commit on master branch

Tags: git, github

We are using Git 1.9.1.

Right now we have two branches master and development. Now we wants that developer can commit only to development branch and they do not have permission to commit on master branch.

We are using [github.com](http://github.com) and our repository is private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since GitHub does not have branch protection ([as opposed to Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Branch+management)), you would need to use 2 private repos, not one.

- one private repo for the master branch managers
- one private repo, which can be [set up as a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/), for the developers

When they want, the developers can initiate [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) from the fork to the main repo.